# hide part of paragrah\table - js jquery ajax

Tags: javascript

i have a problem - i bulid two tables inside a paragraph and i need to hide only one of the tables in a way that when i will show it again it will stay with same structure before the hiding and i need your  help.

this is the code:

```
$('#BtnA').click(function(){
                $.ajax('https://travelbriefing.org/countries.json',
                {
                    dataType:'json',
                    timeout:5000000,
                    success:function(data,status,xhr){
                        $.each(data, function(i, f) {
                         if(f.name[0]=='A'){
                        var  tbllRow = "<table>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.name + "</td>" +
           "<td>" + "<button2>" +"<button>click for details </button>"+"</button2>"   + "</td>"   + "</tr>" + "</table>"
          
                $.ajax(f.url,
                {
                    dataType:'json',
                    timeout:5000000,
                    success:function(data,status,xhr){
                        $.each(data,function(i,f){
                            var tbllSecRow = "<table>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Languages" + "</td>" +
           "<td>" + f.Language   + "</td>"   + "</tr>" + "<tr>"+ "<td>"+ "Currency"+ "</td>"+ "<td>"+f.currency +"</td>"+ "</tr>"+"</table>"
             $('p2').append(tbllRow);
           $('p2').append(tbllSecRow);
```

and i uploaded the image of the structure[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjIO5.jpg)

i need only to hide the languague and currency part and show each one of them when there is a click in a button...
thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

You can create one css class lets say .toggleDisplay { display: none };
Add this class to language and currency column, and toggle this class on button click,
Also add one more common class to access on button click say - toggleAccess to language and currency
e.g.

```
td will be like <td class="toggleDisplay toggleAccess "> language/currency</td>
$("button").click(function(){
  $(".toggleAccess ").toggleClass("toggleDisplay ");
});
```

Comment: but  i need to do it inside tbllSecRow.. how is it possible? i tried to do what you suggest inside tbllSecRow (td class="toggleDisplay toggleAccess ") and it didnt respond

Comment: Means click not working right ? Did you try to debug same ? If click not working try to add click handler like $(document).on("click", "button" , function() { // logic }); This is the way to add click handlers for dynamically created html element. Hope this will help. You can add some class to button and use it in attaching click handler instead of directly on button.